# Postback hidden column data with JQGrid and MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a JQGrid with a hidden column, I would like the data in this column to be posted back to the server when the user edits it in the edit dialog box.

As it stands, the only way I can see this form data in the postback is when using the column property `Editable = true`, however, this then displays a text input box on the dialog. With `Editable = false` the input box is hidden but the value is not in the postback.

Having the property displayed in the edit dialog is not ideal as I don't want the user to be able to change the value, but I need it posted back to the server for business logic reasons.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have tagged you question with `jqgrid-asp.net` tag, are you using any kind of helper library?

Comment: I'm using the MVC API that comes with JQGrid if that's what you're asking?

Comment: **jqGrid** itself is just JavaScript library, there is no ASP.NET MVC specific API. Maybe you have bought **jqSuite** from Trirand or you are using some other server side library. The answer is important because the scenario you have described should work out of the box, but if you are using some kind of wrapping library it may be doing some kind of *short circuit* under the hood.

Comment: Oh right, ok well in that case yes, it's JQSuite that we're using. Sorry for the confusion. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to quite work out of the box as I can't find a way to hide a column from the grid and edit dialog but still have the value in the postback. If you can point me to some documentation that describes this I would appreciate it.

Comment: So what happens when you define your column like this: `new JQGridColumn { DataField = "FieldName", Hidden = true, Editable = true }`

Comment: Interesting, the JQGridColumn class doesn't have a Hidden property, I'm using JQSuite 4.5.0 by the way. The properties I'm using are Visible = false and Editable = true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the data in client side by `$('#tr_<ColumnName>').hide();`
Use it in appropriate places like in ADD and EDIT functions of the JqGrid.
I solved the problem through this way. Any elegant suggestion is welcome.
P.S - Actually credit goes to my team-mates. They found the way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks like this is the best way to tackle the problem at present.